# Using Lagrange Multipliers for undefinite functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I came across with this problem the other day and I had no idea how to solve it.

The problem said that if you know that the maximum of a function $f$ is -250 when given a constraint $g(x,y)=150$ and that in the process you got that $\lambda=-2$, estimate the maximum of $f$ when given a constraint $g(x,y)=153$ using Lagrange multipliers.

I know how the Lagrange multipliers work and I still don't know how to approach it, I tried to take as much information from the problem as I could, but because I don't know how $f$ and $g$ are, I don't know how to estimate that value. I know that we have that:

$f_x=2g_x$

$f_y=2g_y$

But that still doesn't tell me nothing, can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the linear approximations $$g(x+\Delta x, y+ \Delta y) \sim g(x,y)+ g_x(x,y)\Delta x + g_y(x,y)\Delta y$$ $$f(x+\Delta x, y+ \Delta y) \sim f(x,y)+ f_x(x,y)\Delta x + f_y(x,y)\Delta y$$

From the first we deduce that, at the point in question,  $$153= g(x+\Delta x, y+ \Delta y) \sim g(x,y)+ g_x(x,y)\Delta x + g_y(x,y)\Delta y= 150 + g_x(x,y)\Delta x + g_y(x,y)\Delta y$$

Whence $$g_x(x,y)\Delta x + g_y(x,y)\Delta y\sim 3$$

FRom the second we deduce that $$f(x+\Delta x, y+ \Delta y) \sim f(x,y)+ 2g_x(x,y)\Delta x + 2g_y(x,y)\Delta y\sim f(x,y)+6 = -244$$

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didn't think about considering those approximations with the delta of x and y considered. You are the best!